# When exception occurs should I raise or bubble it up?

Tags: python, exception

I'm implementing endpoint at tornado app and have doubts how to raise and handle exceptions.

I have get method which collects all raised exceptions and logs them. It looks like this:

```
def get(self):
    try:
        req = self.get_request_params()
    except Exception as e:
        self.send_json(status_code=400, status_text=str(e))
        logging.exception(str(e))
```

And here is `get_request_params` which might throw an exception:

```
def get_request_params(self):
    try:
        user_id = UUID(self.get_query_argument("user_id", None))
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect argument value for user_id = %s" % user_id)

    try:
        from_date = self.get_query_argument("from", default=None)
        datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect argument value for from_date = %s, should be YYYY-MM-DD" % from_date)
    ...
```

There are also other request params, which checked in the same way. Looks like I'm trying to do more than necessary. Instead of it I can have something like this:

```
def get_request_params(self):
    user_id = UUID(self.get_query_argument("user_id", None))
    from_date = self.get_query_argument("from", default=None)
    datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    ...
```

In such case any exception will bubble up and will be handled at `get` method. However, I will lost those pretty messages.

So, should I be so explicit in raising exceptions or it's enough to permit thing go as they are?

Comment: I'd let the exceptions bubble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you catch an exception, it means you intend to do *something* about it, even if that something is just output a custom logging message before ignoring it or re-raising it. If the *only* thing you do is re-raise it, then you shouldn't have caught it in the first place. (This *might* indicate that the class of error you are catching is too broad.)

Comment: "... you shouldn't have caught it in the first place." Yes.

Comment: In general: No. Catching the exception allows for a less generic error being propagated, which may be valuable for the target group. In this special case the error thrown by `strptime` is already very close to the message op raises. There is, however, one additional information: It's the `from-date` raising the complaint. When there are more dates in the game, this might be a valuable additional info and may justify the `except`.